# How to get the default row in WPF datagrid as like in WINFORM datagridview

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am a newbie to WPF. I am trying to replicate a functionality that I created in Winform datagridview in WPF datagrid. 
When I created the datagridview with required columns and ran the application it provided a default empty row. I started editing the default row at runtime and added more rows to the datagridview . But when I did the samething in WPF I didnt get the default empty row. Because of this I am not able to add content to each of the columns.
I need an empty datagrid, which I would use it at runtime to get input from the user.
Please help me on this...!

Regards
Dhana

Please see my XMAL below

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="850">
    <Window.Resources>
        <col:ArrayList x:Key="CriteriaTypeList">
            <col:DictionaryEntry Key="SINGLE" Value="SINGLE"/>
            <col:DictionaryEntry Key="MULTIPLE" Value="MULTIPLE"/>
        </col:ArrayList>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="350" Width="800" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" FontSize="13" CanUserAddRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="CriteriaType" Width="1*" ItemsSource="{StaticResource CriteriaTypeList}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Priority" Width="1*"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Condition" Width="2*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="(" Width="1*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data Item" Width="3*"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Values" Width="1*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header=")" Width="1*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Have you set `CanUserAddRows` to `False` on dataGrid instance because default value is true and empty row is available always.

Comment: Yes I have added CanUserAddRows="True". Please see my XAML code here.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set **`Binding`** for any of the columns. Set Binding to some property in underlying ItemsSource so that dataGrid get to know what to show in its row and you will see blank row in dataGrid.

```
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,44,0,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="350" Width="800" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" FontSize="13" CanUserAddRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            .....
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Priority" Width="1*"
                                Binding="{Binding PropertyName}"/> <-- HERE
            .....
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I modified my code to capture the Binding information but now I am getting stackoverflow exception.

Comment: Try to debug your code. That is completely unrelated to this post. Please raise separate question for that with relevant code.